# Time's Up? Why?

Tags: meaning, semantics

Why do we use these sorts of optical inaccuracies. One would think time's up means that your time has increased.

Another example is "I'm down". Down generally has a negative connotation.

What's the explanation behind these?

Comment: I think it's mostly informal usage. It's also the name of a movement, (similar to?) the Me Too movement.

Answer (score 2):

"Time's up" doesn't mean that your time has increased. If we say "time's up", that means the time is at an end.

Also, saying "I'm down (as an adverb, except adverb of place)" means in or into a weaker or worse position, mood, or condition.

Comment: I think OP understands what it means.  He's asking "why ***up***?"

Comment: "I'm down" can also mean, "I'm down for that." which means "I'm interested. I'm game. I'm willing."

Comment: @Jin: I think you are right. Did you use "down" as positive connotation.

Comment: Yes.  Consider the following exchsnge: A: “I’m thinking about going out for pizza” B: “I love pizza-  I’m down for that. When do you want to leave?”

Comment: @Jim is right, I do in fact know the actual meaning lmao

Answer (score 2):

In Merriam-Webster, the word [**up**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/up) has *eleven* different main senses, along with minor variations:

> **1 a** (1) : in or into a higher position or level; especially : away from the center of the earth (2) : from beneath the ground or water to the surface
>   (3) : from below the horizon (4) : UPSTREAM (5) : in or into an upright position · sit *up* ; especially : out of bed
>   **b** : upward from the ground or surface · pull *up* a daisy
>   **c** : so as to expose a particular surface
>   **2** : with greater intensity · speak *up*
>   **3 a** : in or into a better or more advanced state
>   **b** : at an end · your time is *up*
>   **c** : in or into a state of greater intensity or excitement
>   **d** : to or at a greater speed, rate, or amount · prices went *up*
>   **e** : in a continual sequence : in continuance from a point or to a point · from third grade *up* · at prices of $10 and *up* · *up* until now
>   **4 a** (1) : into existence, evidence, prominence, or prevalence (2) : into operation or practical form
>   **b** : into consideration or attention · bring *up* for discussion
>   **5** : into possession or custody
>   **6 a** : ENTIRELY, COMPLETELY · button *up* your coat
>   **b** —used as an intensifier · clean *up* the house
>   **7** : in or into storage : BY · lay *up* supplies
>   **8 a** : so as to arrive or approach
>   **b** : in a direction conventionally the opposite of down: (1) : to windward (2) : NORTHWARD (3) : to or at the top (4) : to or at the rear of a theatrical stage
>   **9** : in or into parts
>   **10** : to a stop —usually used with *draw*, *bring*, *fetch*, or *pull*
>   **11** : for each side · the score is 15 *up*

Sense **3 b** (*at an end*) is directly relevant, and sense **10** (*to a stop*) is related.

To say that *time's up* should be associated with *increased* (sense **3 b** or **3 d**) rather than a different sense—in particular those it actually relates to—seems arbitrary. It's use may actually make perfect sense.

To fully answer this, you'd have to know what senses were defined (or in use) when the phrase *your time is up* was actually coined.

---

Similarly, [**down**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/down) also has many senses—I'll only reference the relevant ones this time (you need to scroll down the webpage that's linked to see these):

> **2 a** : reduced or low in activity, frequency, or intensity · a *down* economy
>   **b** : not operating or able to function · The computer is *down*.
>   **c** : depressed, dejected · feeling a bit *down* · ; also : depressing · a *down* movie
>   **d** : sick · *down* with flu
>   **4** : completely mastered · had her lines *down* —often used with *pat* · got the answers *down* pat
>   **5 a** *slang* : COOL · a *down* dude
>   **b** *slang* : understanding or supportive of something or someone —usually used with *with* · trying to prove that they were *down* with hip-hop culture —J. E. White 
>   **6** : being on record · you're *down* for two tickets

In the sense that you used *down* in your question (especially since you mean it to have a negative connotation), it follows the senses **2 a–d**. *I'm down* is likely short for *I'm feeling down*, meaning sick or depressed.

However, it need not. It could also be short for *I'm down with that*, which has a positive connotation. (Oddly, *I'm down with that* and *I'm up for that* seem to be synonymous.) It means *I'm cool with that*, *count me in*, or *that sounds good to me*, and is related to senses **4–5**.

---

I will leave it to somebody else to trace the specific etymology of these phrases.